# Ajax post failing in asp

Tags: php, asp.net, javascript, jquery, ajax

hey guys, this might be really stupid, but hopefully someone can help. I'm trying to post to an external script using ajax so i can mail the data, but for some reason my data is not making it to the script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submitContactForm").click(function () {
    $('#loading').append('<img src="http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/demo/copyshop/images/loading.gif" alt="Currently Loading" id="loadingComment" />');
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var comment = $('#comment').val();
        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&comment=' + comment;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.xxxxx.com/demo/copyshop/php/sendmail.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: '?name=Dave&email=xxxxxxx@gmail.com&comment=hiiii',
            success: function(result) {
                $('#loading').append('success');
                }
            });    

    return false;
});
});
```

the php script is simple (for now - just wanted to make sure it worked)

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

$to = 'xxxxx@xxxxx.com';
$subject = 'New Contact Inquiry';
$message = $comment;

mail($to, $subject, $message);
?>
```

the jquery is embedded in an .aspx page (a language i'm not familiar with) but is posting to a php script. i'm receiving emails properly but there is no data inside. am i missing something? i tried to bypass the variables in this example, but its still not working

thanks

Comment: If you sniff the traffic being sent with fiddler or httpfox, is the data present? And remove the '?' in the data field - it shouldn't be there.

Comment: Also, can you verify whether both scripts are running on the same domain or not? Some has obviously interpreted the different number of x's in the domain names as to mean different domains..

Comment: the processing script is located on a different domain than the jquery code

Comment: problem is, i can't create pages on domain A - i can only insert html/javascript into an existing page using a custom page editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't using Ajax to talk to a site that isn't in the [same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) as the document your script is running in, unless both the browser and the destination support [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/). You can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) to work around it a bit, but really CORS is the future in this regard.

Comment: do you have a suggestion to the best way around this?

Comment: who said anything about different domains?

Comment: the processing script is on another domain.

Comment: @Dave Kiss: CORS and JSONP *are* the suggestions. :-) Before those came on the scene I'd've said do it server-side: You send your request to a page on your server, which sends the request to the other domain, and then gives you the response (e.g., proxies it). Aside from those, you start getting into signed Java applets/Flash apps/ActiveX controls...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use AJAX to send a request to a different domain.

Comment: You  can make a proxy script in your domain that forwards the request to the other domain.

Comment: can you tell me more about your option slaks?

Comment: Make a PHP (or ASP.Net) page on your domain that sends the request to the other domain.

Comment: problem is, i can't create pages on domain A - i can only insert html/javascript into an existing page using a custom page editor

Answer (score 0):

Remove the '?' character from your data. I'm guessing this is messing up the data parsing in PHP.

When posting the data should be encoded using `encodeURIComponent` and this will encode `?` as  `%3F`.